# Work-around for Google Sheet limit on IMPORTXML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import data to a Google sheet using the function IMPORTXML.
Apparently there's a limit to how many times you can use the function in a sheet. If you reach the limit the formula will get stuck in "loading...".
I get this issue using it no more than 20 times.

I need to get data from >200 urls. I therefore want to create a Google sheet script that runs the IMPORTXML in a few cells and copies the result and pastes as values. Then loop this with new url input.

Seems like a simple script...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {

  //copy url from list in X-column:
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("X"+(2+x)).
  copyTo(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("A2"));

  //paste result from IMPORTXML formulas as values on row 250+:
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("B2:C2").
  copyTo(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("B"+(250+x)+":C"+(250+x)), 
  {contentsOnly:true});

}
```

The result from the script is that only the values from the last run of the loop are repeated on each row. I've tried a delays in the script, (Utilities.sleep(1000)) to allow the cells to update, but it doesn't help.

Any other ideas for how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you tired using [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush). I would apply a flush after copying the url.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. It almost worked :)
Now I got the correct results in the first 2 loop itereations, so it's a step forward, but then it went back to copying the "Loading..." message.

Comment: Combine use of `Utilities.sleep(n)` and `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`? I'm sure there are some imports that take a little while to process...

Comment: The IMPORTXML function is completely unreliable :/ Sometimes it gets stuck and it takes several minutes to load just a single value. I've now removed the loop function and replaced it with a manual button. I'm about to start the journey of pressing an ugly home-made google sheet button 250 times.

Comment: Or you can use [`urlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String))

Comment: I added a flush and sleep do-while loop before the pasting. The script seems to be working but it's really slow. I'll just let it run over night and hope that it succeeds. The script now looks something like this:

1. Update URL reference.
2.
  do {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    var loadCount = cell reference with (=countif("loading...")-statement
  }while (loadCount > 0);

3. Paste result as values.
4. Repeat.